# Inverting the depolarizing channel

Tags: quantum-operation, linear-algebra, depolarizing-channel, shadow-tomography

I have a depolarizing channel acting on $2^n \times 2^n$ Hermitian matrices, defined as

$$\tag{1}
\mathcal{D}_p (X) = p X + (1-p) \frac{\text{Tr}(X)}{2^n} \mathbb{I}_{2^n}
$$

where $\mathbb{I}_{d}$ is the identity operator on $d$ dimensions. I am wondering how to derive the inverse of this map, $\mathcal{D}_p^{-1}$. I found the following formula in ([Huang, 2020](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-020-0932-7?proof=t), eqn S37) which is easily verifiable:

$$\tag{2}
\mathcal{D}_{1/(2^n+1)} (X) = (2^n + 1) X - \text{Tr}(X)\mathbb{I}_{2^n}
$$

but the authors never explicitly required $\text{Tr}(X)=1$ (nor is it implied from their notation). In this case, how does one derive the inverse to $(1)$?

Comment: I don't quite understand why ${\rm Tr}(X)=1$ should be required for this? Do you mean because if that's the case then ${\cal D}_p(X)$ is linear in $X$ and thus the inversion trivial?

Comment: yes i now realize its not required, but i was able to initially assume pure states to make the inversion very simple. When I originally came up with the question I was getting stuck on the issue that trace isn't generally invertible but I see that's not an issue now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The existence of the inverse of a linear map is independent of the way the map affects the trace. Moreover, if an invertible map preserves a property then its inverse necessarily also preserves the property. Since depolarizing channel preserves the trace, so does its inverse.

### Inverse of depolarizing channel

We can derive the formula for the inverse $\mathcal{D}_p^{-1}$ of a depolarizing channel $\mathcal{D}_p$ from the observation that the depolarizing parameter $p$ is multiplicative over channel composition, i.e. $\mathcal{D}_p\circ\mathcal{D}_q = \mathcal{D}_{pq}$. This implies that $\mathcal{D}^{-1}_p = \mathcal{D}_{1/p}$.

More explicitly, depolarizing channel $\mathcal{D}_p: L(\mathcal{H}) \to L(\mathcal{H})$ has the property that for any operator $X\in L(\mathcal{H})$

$$
\begin{align}
D_p(D_q(X)) &= p\left(qX + (1-q)\frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}\mathrm{tr}(X)\right) + (1-p)\frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}\mathrm{tr}(X) \\
&= pqX + (1-pq)\frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}\mathrm{tr}(X) \\
&= D_{pq}(X)
\end{align}
$$

where $d=\dim\mathcal{H}$. Therefore, if $p\ne 0$ then the inverse of $\mathcal{D}_p$ is $\mathcal{D}_{1/p}$ since then we have that

$$
\mathcal{D}_p \circ \mathcal{D}_{1/p} = \mathcal{D}_{1/p} \circ \mathcal{D}_p = \mathcal{D}_{p \cdot 1/p} = \mathcal{D}_1 = \mathcal{I}.
$$

If $p=0$, then $\mathcal{D}_0$ is constant on density operators and therefore does not have an inverse.

### CP constraint

A linear map describes a physical process without post-selection, if it is completely positive (CP) and trace preserving (TP). Depolarizing channel $\mathcal{D}_p$ is completely positive if and only if $p\in\left[-\frac{1}{d^2-1}, 1\right]$. Moreover, if $p\in\left[-\frac{1}{d^2-1}, 1\right]$ and $\frac1p\in\left[-\frac{1}{d^2-1}, 1\right]$ then $p=1$. Therefore, the only completely positive depolarizing channel with completely positive inverse is the identity channel.

### TP constraint

On the other hand, $\mathcal{D}_p$ preserves the trace for every $p$ and so the inverse $\mathcal{D}_{1/p}$ also preserves the trace. This is a special case of a general fact that if an invertible function $f$ preserves a property then its inverse $f^{-1}$ necessarily also preserves the property.

Comment: The multiplicative property is a neat observation. This makes me believe that other channels having this property would also have a corresponding shadow tomography protocol thats simple to represent.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the channel is trace preserving so its straightforward to invert in this case. Let $Y = \mathcal{D}_p (X)$ so that
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}(Y)  &= p\text{Tr}(X) + (1-p) \frac{\text{Tr}(X)}{2^n} \text{Tr}\left(\mathbb{I}_{2^n}\right) 
\\&= \text{Tr}(X)
\end{align}

So that
\begin{align}
Y &= p X + (1-p) \frac{\text{Tr}(Y)}{2^n} \mathbb{I}_{2^n}
\\\Rightarrow X &= \frac{1}{p}Y - (\frac{1}{p}-1) \frac{\text{Tr}(Y)}{2^n} \mathbb{I}_{2^n}
\\&= \mathcal{D}_p^{-1}(Y)
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}_{1/p}^{-1}(X) = pX - (p-1) \frac{\text{Tr}(X)}{2^n} \mathbb{I}_{2^n}
\end{align}
which recovers $(2)$ with $p=2^n + 1$.